# Bash printf formatting not working!

Tags: bash, text-formatting, printf

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
num1=32.55
num2=145.958
printf "%5.2f\n" $num1
printf "%5.2f\n" $num2
```

The output is:

```
32.55
145.96
```

Instead of:

```
   32.55
  145.96
```

What's going on? If it's any help, I'm using Fedora 27 Beta with `Linux Kernel 4.13.8-300.fc27.x86_64`

Answer (score 6):

The width specifier is for *all* characters including the decimal point and fraction. Your numbers already have at least 5 characters, so...

```
$ printf "%8.2f\n" 32.55
   32.55
```

Comment: So basically it's %(total).(num after decimal)f ?

Comment: For `f` and similar, yes.